# Unexpected behaviour in MySQL with Boolean-Mode-Query with quoted hyphenated string

Tags: mysql, match-against

I have a problem or rather an understanding problem with a hyphenated searchstring which is quoted.

In my Table there is a table with a column 'company'.
One of the entries in that column is: **A-Z Electro**

The following examples are simplified a lot (though the real query is much more complex) - but the effect is still the same.

When I do the following search, I don't get the row with the above mentioned company:

```
SELECT  i.*
FROM my_table i
WHERE MATCH (i.company) AGAINST ('+\"A-Z\" +Electro*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
GROUP BY i.uid ORDER BY i.company ASC LIMIT 0, 40;
```

If I do the following search, get the row with the above mentioned company (notice only changed the - to a + before "A-Z":

```
SELECT  i.*
FROM my_table i
WHERE MATCH (i.company) AGAINST ('-\"A-Z\" +Electro*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
GROUP BY i.uid ORDER BY i.company ASC LIMIT 0, 40;
```

I also get the row, if I remove the operator completely:

```
SELECT  i.*
FROM my_table i
WHERE MATCH (i.company) AGAINST ('\"A-Z\" +Electro*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
GROUP BY i.uid ORDER BY i.company ASC LIMIT 0, 40;
```

Can anyone explain to me this behaviour? Because I would expect, when searching with a +, I should get the result too...

I just checked the table index with myisam_ftdump.
Two-Character-Words are indexed properly as there are entries like

```
14f2e8 0.7908264 ab  
3a164 0.8613265 dv
```

There is also an entry:

```
de340 0.6801047 az
```

I suppose this should be the entry for A-Z - so the search should find this entry, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

The default value of `ft_min_word_len` is 4. See [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len) for information on that. In short, your system isn't indexing words of less than 4 characters.

Why is this important? Well:

- `A-Z` is less than 4 characters long
- ...therefore it's not in the index
- ...but your first query `+"A-Z"` states it must be in the index in order for the match to succeed
- The other two (match if it's not in the index, match if either this or that is in the index) work because it's *not* in the index.

The hyphen is a red herring - the reason is because "A-Z" is three characters long and your FT index ignores it.

Comment: @"Jeremy Smith" Sorry, forgot to mention that: ft_min_word_len is set to 3

Comment: Did you rebuild your index after setting it to 3?

Comment: The setting is nothing I changed recently. The setting is set to 2 (and ft_stopword_file='') since almost a year and since then the index has been rebuilt many times and also the MySQL Server has been restarted many times. I updated my post above => index is ok, however the search still doesn't match... Any other ideas?